# openpyxl write to single column append()?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm attempting to locate data within a spreadsheet that meets certain criteria.  The spreadsheet has approximately 9000 rows and 16 columns.  I'm matching an ID in any row in column 1 and returning the value from that row located in column 12.  So far I'm finding the data I want and adding it to a list.  I now want to write that information to a new sheet and single column row by row.  I'm using append() but that is writing out across columns.

Update:  So in continuing to review this.  The cell containing the information I want contains quite a bit of text, its a list of software with new line breaks throughout, it looks like below (all in a single cell):

> The following software are installed on the remote host :
> 7-Zip 19.00 (x64)  [version 19.00]
> Dell EqualLogic SAN Headquarters  [version 3.4.0.9366]  [installed on 12/28/2018]
> Google Chrome  [version 91.0.4472.77]  [installed on 2021/06/01]
> Matrox Graphics Software (remove only)
> McAfee Agent  [version 5.7.2.162]
> Microsoft Visual J# 2.0 Redistributable Package - SE (x64)
> Notepad++ (64-bit x64)  [version 7.5.8]
> OpenSSL 1.1.0i (32-bit)  [installed on 2018/08/30]

I'm trying to split this on line breaks and create a new worksheet with each software item and version in a single column.

In the console it will return:

> [['Plugin Output: ', 'The following software are installed on the remote host :', '', 'McAfee Agent  [version 5.7.2.162]', 'Axway Desktop Validator  [version 4.12.0.4.0]  [installed on 2021/04/26]', 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 x86 Minimum Runtime - 12.0.21005  [version 12.0.21005]  [installed on 2020/01/02]', 'McAfee Data Exchange Layer for MA  [version 6.0.30278.0]  [installed on 2021/04/03]', 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2010  x64 Redistributable - 10.0.40219  [version 10.0.40219]  [installed on 2020/10/01]', 'Hotfix for Microsoft Visual C++ 2010  x64 Redistributable (KB2151757)  [version 1]', 'Hotfix for Microsoft Visual C++ 2010  x64 Redistributable (KB2467173)  [version 1]', 'Hotfix for Microsoft Visual C++ 2010  x64 Redistributable (KB2565063)  [version 1]', 'Hotfix for Microsoft Visual C++ 2010  x64 Redistributable (KB982573)  [version 1]']]

I want the data return to be appended in the new worksheet in column A but it puts it into a single row across multiple columns.  Any thoughts?

```
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter
import re
#load the workbook
wb = load_workbook('excel/TEST_FILES.xlsx', keep_vba=False)
#variable for activer worksheet, the first one
ws = wb.active

software = []

for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_col=1,):
     #look into if this is needed
     for cell in row:       
         if cell.value == 20811:
             swlist = cell.offset(0,12).value
             dalist = swlist.split('\n')
             software.append(dalist)


 nws = wb.create_sheet("SWLIST")

 #appends each item to the new sheet & saves
 for item in software:
     nws.append(item)
     wb.save('excel/TEST_FILES.xlsx')
 print(software)
```

I've made some progress and updated the above "append code" to the following.  Not I can get it to append a single index reference but not sure how to loop through each item.

Updated code:

```
 #appends each item to the new sheet & saves
 for item in software:
      nws.append({'A':item[5]})  
      wb.save('excel/TEST_FILES.xlsx')
```

####UPDATE:
Still working through the append. I'm not having luck on getting it to append to a single column all the software listed.  I'm looking at making it into a dictionary and then appending it?  see below but it returns a syntax error.

```
for item in software:
     software = dict(zip('A',item)
     nws.append.(software)
```

ERROR:  File "D:\Dev_Projects\ExcelRangeLoop.py", line 25
nws.append.(software)
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

*******UPDATED CODE THAT WORKS UP TO WHERE I NEED IT TO FOR NOW******

```
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter

#load the workbook
wb = load_workbook('excel/TEST_FILES.xlsx', keep_vba=False)

#variable for active worksheet, the first one
ws = wb.active

software = []
for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_col=1,):
    #look into if this is needed
     for cell in row:
         if cell.value == 20811:
             swlist = cell.offset(0,12).value
             dalist = swlist.split('\n')
             software = dalist
#Removes the unecessary info contained within the cell values
 software.remove('Plugin Output: ')
 software.remove('')
 del software[35:]
#new worksheet
 nws = wb.create_sheet("SWLIST")
#appends each item to the new sheet & saves
 for item in range(len(software)):
     nws.append({'A':software[item]})
print(software)
wb.save('excel/TEST_FILES.xlsx')
```

Comment: So what you want is to updated those data into a new sheet with different row but with same column? You can use a helper index to to that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Yes, each data (software name) in column A only and keep on listing them down the column by row.. row 1 - 100 or whatever.

Comment: Not sure on the help index.  I'm actually testing out the below but getting a syntax error:
     for item in software:
        software = dict(zip('A',item)
        nws.append.(software)

Comment: I just answered with a code example.

Answer (score 1):

Try using index to fill the rows. Did not test out this code, but it should work.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter
import re
#load the workbook
wb = load_workbook('excel/TEST_FILES.xlsx', keep_vba=False)
#variable for activer worksheet, the first one
ws = wb.active

software = []

for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_col=1,):
     #look into if this is needed
     for cell in row:       
         if cell.value == 20811:
             swlist = cell.offset(0,12).value
             dalist = swlist.split('\n')
             software.append(dalist)


nws = wb.create_sheet("SWLIST")

ind = nws.max_row
for i in range(len(software)):
    nws[f'A{i+ind}'] = software[i]

wb.save('excel/TEST_FILES.xlsx')
#appends each item to the new sheet & saves
print(software)
```

Comment: Thanks for that info.  It started me down a path and I've figured out my issue and gotten to the next part of my code.    Right now it
1. Searches for ID and finds it.
2. Creates new sheet and parses the values into a single column by row with the software names I needed.    See the update w/ the new code.

Comment: The way I usually deal with search xlsx file with openpyxl is to have two list. The first list contains all IDs, usually a column, and the other list is their index, like ['item1,'item2'], [0,1]. And then if I'm looking for  item2, I will search its index in the first index which is 1, and map with the second list. This way you can have it, you can also use dict to do the same thing. Think about this, and you can also solve part 2, record the software names and their index, and then order the two index at same time, and then just move the values into new sheet.